# Conditional Probability Denominator doubt

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let X be a rv such that $P(X = 2) = 1/4$ and its CDF is given by
$$F_{X}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  0,&  x< -3\\    
  \frac{3}{4}(x+3),& -3\leq x <2 \\ 
  3/4,& 2 \leq x <4\\
  \frac{3}{64} x^2,& 4 \leq x < \frac{8}{\sqrt{3}} \\
  1,& x \geq \frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}  
\end{cases}
$$

$x=2$ in the only discontinuity of $F$.
I have to compute $P(X<3|X \geq 2)$.

My way is: $\frac{P(2 \leq X<3)}{P(X \geq2)}$ = $\frac{F(3)- F(2) - P(X = 3) + P(X=2)}{1 - P(X<2)}$

$P(X= 3) = 0$ because it is continuous there.
How can I compute the denominator.

Comment: There is a  typo. What you have typed is not a CDF. You should change $8 \sqrt 3$ to $\frac 8 {\sqrt 3}$.

Comment: Hello Unknown. What does CDF and rv mean? Ah, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: @ Unknown : The current CDF is wrong. It cannot be $\frac{3}{4}(x+3)$ when $-3 \leq x <2$ because it is $F(2^-)>1$

The previous was right...$F_X(x)=\frac{x+3}{10}$, according with $P(X=2)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Please amend the text

Answer (score 1):

$P(X>2)=\int_4^{8/\sqrt3 } \frac 3  {32} xdx=\frac 1  4$. Add $P(X=2)=\frac 1  4$ to this to get $P(X \geq 2)$.

Comment: Thanks!! I have corrected the question.. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Having the CDF no integral is needed.

You can solve the problem in this way

$$\mathbb{P}[Z<3|X\geq 2]=\frac{F_X(3)-F_X(2^-)}{1-F_X(2^-)}=\frac{\frac{3}{4}-[\frac{x+3}{10}]_{x=2}}{1-[\frac{x+3}{10}]_{x=2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

The current CDF is wrong. It cannot be $\frac{3}{4}(x+3)$ when $-3 \leq x <2$ because it is $F(2^-)>1$

The previous was right...$F_X(x)=\frac{x+3}{10}$, according with $P(X=2)=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Why did you do Fx(2\^-), when there is equality sign in 2?

Comment: @Unknown : because you have to include $P(X=2)$

Comment: @Unknown : or equivalently, $P(X \geq2)=1-P(X<2)=1-F_X(2^-)$